# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have the dependency defined in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the above jar in **C:/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.3.0.ga**

I've got a session-factory and datasource configured in a hibernate.cfg.xml and while trying to build the configuration in my main method:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
```

I've tried adding the hibernate-commons-annotion jar straight in my Build Path as well as my WEB-INF/lib, but no luck yet

This is setup the same way and running properly on another application I've built, which didn't need the annotations jar imported.
Any ideas?

Comment: After searching for a couple hours through other solutions I figured it couldn't hurt to ask since someone else might have had the same issue, but HEY sorry for posting a question on SO-a place for technical questions. Flagged.

Comment: go the the API, and check if that class exist. if you can't find it, it means that there are comparability issue. That method may have been deprecated or else.

Comment: compabiliby issue: find a version that is compatible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently 3.3.0.ga was a 'mistake', had to update dependency to use 3.2.0.Final

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Source**: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-711