# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' in my project with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm doing a project to study java spring boot When I was to create persistence, found the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoaderDelegate
```

my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my src/main/resources/application.properties
in my bd no have password..

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlinebanking
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = ""
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

thanks for listening

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means you are missing a dependency (jar).  If I had to guess you are missing the same dependency referenced in the following:

[NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755760/noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-annotations-common-reflection-metadataprovid)